# If not null - java 8 style

Tags: java, lambda, java-8, option-type

Java 8 presents `Optional` class.

Before (Java 7):

```
Order order = orderBean.getOrder(id);
if (order != null) {
    order.setStatus(true);
    pm.persist(order);
} else {
    logger.warning("Order is null");
}
```

So on Java 8 style:

```
Optional<Order> optional = Optional.ofNullable(orderBean.getOrder(id));
optional.ifPresent( s -> {
    s.setStatus(true);
    pm.persist(s);
    //Can we return from method in this place (not from lambda) ???
});
//So if return take place above, we can avoid if (!optional.isPresent) check
if (!optional.isPresent) {
    logger.warning("Order is null");
}
```

Is it correct to use `Optional` in this case? Can anyone propose a more convenient way in Java 8 style?

Comment: It's inefficient, but cleaner way, you can get the element inside Optional inside try block and catch NoSuchElementException exception.

Answer (score 12):

Unfortunately, the `ifPresentOrElse` method you're looking for [will be added](http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk9/dev/jdk/file/f160dec9a350/src/java.base/share/classes/java/util/Optional.java#l164) only in JDK-9. Currently you can write your own static method in your project:

```
public static <T> void ifPresentOrElse(Optional<T> optional,
        Consumer<? super T> action, Runnable emptyAction) {
    if (optional.isPresent()) {
        action.accept(optional.get());
    } else {
        emptyAction.run();
    }
}
```

And use like this:

```
Optional<Order> optional = Optional.ofNullable(orderBean.getOrder(id));
ifPresentOrElse(optional, s -> {
    s.setStatus(true);
    pm.persist(s);
}, () -> logger.warning("Order is null"));
```

In Java-9 it would be easier:

```
optional.ifPresentOrElse(s -> {
    s.setStatus(true);
    pm.persist(s);
}, () -> logger.warning("Order is null"));
```

Comment: This would become an improvement only if OP had to parameterize the function with the handling logic. As it is, his code is a perfect match for the plain old if-else.

Comment: @MarkoTopolnik, I don't say I like this solution. Actually I don't like Optionals and rarely use them. In this code I would definitely avoid them.

Comment: Good answer. `Optional` class = easy stuff written in a complicated way. I really see no reason to use this class at all, you need much more letters to write your code in this "modern" way...

Comment: @vojta Let's be fair to Optional, it is a great tool when you have a "happy-day" path through some transformation code and want to deal with the distractions of nulls separately. It really does improve the code a lot there.

Comment: @vojta, optionals are great in some rare cases (for example, in stream terminal operations), but it's not a feature for everyday use.

Comment: Using `Optional` doesn't mean you have to use lamda necessarily. **You could just use the `isPresent` method.**

Answer (score 1):

> `//Can we return from method in this plase (not from lambda) ???`

Lambdas do not implement "non-local return" semantics, therefore the answer is no.

Generally, since you need side-effectful action in both the case where the value is present and not, a branching point in the code is essential—whether you wrap it in some fancy API or not. Also, FP generally helps improve referentially transparent transformations (i.e., code built around pure functions) and not side effects, so you won't find much benefit by going through the Optional API.